# Drag opaque Form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have the following code to drag the form and make it transparent when its getting dragged. The problem is that it flickers and isn't dragging smooth. I have a picture on the form, not sure if that's what's causing this. How can I make it not flicker. If I remove the opacity then it's getting dragged fast/smooth.

```
[DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, 
    int lParam);
[DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();

public void Drag(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        this.Opacity = 0.9;
        ReleaseCapture();

        SendMessage(Handle, 0xA1, 0x2, 0);
        this.Opacity = 1;
    }
}

private void Body_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{       
    Drag(e);
}
```

Comment: Generally speaking, GDI (what Windows Forms is based on) doesn't handle opacity very well, it has to alpha blend all of the pixels of the rendered product with all the layers underneath.  WPF (because it relies on Direct X, which can do this on the hardware level) generally does this sort of operation much better.

Comment: Gocha. So there's no way to fix this?

Comment: You can try to move `this.Opacity = 1;` to `ResizeEnd` of the form, which is called when You stop dragging the form. Let me know if this helps. Please also let us know how many controls do You have on this form. Please also write what version of Windows are You using (I suppose that on Vista or Win7 the flickering may not be visible).

Comment: thanks @LukaszM that made a huge difference!!

Comment: No problem :). Have You also tried solution from the answer written by Hans Passant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of properties of the Form and Control class that are "heavy", requiring a great deal of change in the underlying native Windows window.  They are the properties that are associated with the style flags that are passed to the native CreateWindowEx() call.  The Opacity property, along with the TransparencyKey property are like that, when you change them from the default then the window needs another style flag, WS_EX_LAYERED.

That's a problem, given that this style flag is specified when you *create* the window.  Windows has some support for changing them after the window is created with SetWindowsLongPtr() but that's always been spotty.  Particularly so for WS_EX_LAYERED, a lot of stuff happens under the hood when that's turned on.  It is implemented by taking advantage of a hardware feature in the video adapter called "layers".  A layer is a separate chunk of video memory whose pixels are combined with the main memory.  The mixer that supports that provides the opacity effect (multiply) and the transparency key effect (omit).

So changing the Opacity property on the fly, after the window is created is quite difficult.  So much so that WPF completely forbids it.  But Winforms doesn't, it needed to deal with the limitations of Windows 98.  Which also made it difficult to change properties like ShowInTaskbar, RightToLeft, FormBorderStyle.  It uses a *trick* to permit changing these properties, it completely destroys the native window and recreates it, now using the new style flags.

Problem solved, but this does have noticeable side effects.  Inevitably, the window you look at disappears and the new window gets created and painted in the same spot.  That causes the flicker you complained about.  Also, destroying the window causes a lot of internal state to be lost.  Winforms does its best to restore that state as well as it can for the new window, but the "I'm currently being moved" state cannot be restored.  The modal move loop already terminated.

The workaround for this problem is crude but simple.  Set the Opacity property in the Properties window to 99%.  And change your code to restore it to 99 instead of 100.  Now the style bit never has to be changed so you won't get these artifacts anymore.